# Columnwise data hiding in cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

I am novice in Cassandra and there a  table that I need to share with someone, 
on which I need to hide some columns that have sensitive data.

Wanted to know, if there any way to do this, in Cassandra or using any other tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such mechanism in cassandra.

If you are using cassandra 3.0 and above it has concept of materialized views.

**Note:** Using materialized view will result in data duplication and will take up your storage space.